# Mapster - Mapping JOIN query results to DTO with nested collection

Tags: c#, collections, entity-framework-core, mapster

I have an EF Core query that queries a set of SomeRecord entity and does an include on a List property like so :

```
return await _dbContext.Set<SomeRecord>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(r => r.ListOfSomeSubRecord)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This is just the problematic part of this query, there are a LOT more includes and conditions but all the other includes do not act on collections so they don't make the resultset grow in number of records returned.

The actual SQL EF Core generates is absolutely humongous and I decided to make a view to try and speed up this endpoint as well as encapsulate this query directly in SQL Server.  The view returns one row per SomeSubRecord with the information of the associated SomeRecord repeating for each instance of the SomeSubRecord.  With that in mind, I have made the following "entity" class that will map to this view :

```
public sealed class SomeRecord
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}

    public string Name {get; set;}

    public Guid SomeSubRecordId {get; set;}

    public string SomeSubRecordName {get; set;}
}
```

Prior to me adding this, EF Core was perfectly happy mapping the result of its huge query to the original entity which contains a List as a property.  That mapped nicely to my DTO using Mapster's Adapt method without me writing a single line of mapping, here is the DTO :

```
public sealed class SomeRecordResponse
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name {get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<SomeSubRecordResponse> ListOfSomeSubRecords { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to do this mapping myself, I need to convert this "exploded" dataset returned from my view into the response object Collection.  I do not know how EF Core does this, neither do I know how to tell Mapster to do it.

Comment: If you project to DTO by itself via `Select`, query will be NOT humongous. And you do not need View for such simple operation. Also here you have Eager loading, which you cannot mimic via View, only if you deduplicate records by yourself.

Comment: What I showed here is a tiny fraction of the actual query.  It joins to 7 other tables which I omitted since, as mentioned above, they are not part of my issue due to not being collections and being easy to map.  The EF Core query pulls over 100 columns and I probably actually need a quarter of that.  I would argue that writing a view and querying that could speed things up quite a bit.

Comment: Have you tried `AsSplitQuery`? Also, if you load whole objects via `Include`, for sure you will have a tons of columns in SQL.

Comment: I honestly did not realize you could write an include for a single property of an entity, I can mess around with that and try the split query.  How exactly does EF Core perform this "de-duplication"?  In looking at the query it generates there is no GROUP BY or anything like that, it pulls a very similar dataset to my custom view yet it's able to map the sub records into a collection

Comment: I'm trying to aim you that there is `Select`, which is opposite for `Include`. If you want help here, post your original FULL query. Deduplication is done by internal information which fields are keys for specific nesting level. Grouping is not needed, entities are ordered by keys, if key changed - another group created.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to play with `Select` first. Eager loading query which you are tring to reproduce by View is hard to implement and maintain. Better to force EF Core to generate effective SQL query.
Then think if you need Mapster here.

```cs
return await _dbContext.Set<SomeRecord>()
    .Select(r => new SomeRecordResponse
    {
        Id = r.Id,
        Name = r.Name,
        ListOfSomeSubRecords = r.ListOfSomeSubRecord.Select(s => new SomeSubRecordResponse
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            Name = s.Name
        })
    })
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Also take a look at Mapster's [ProjectToType](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster#queryable-extensions) which should generate similar `Select` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use mapster after all your query and before .TiLost or any thing use .ProjectTotype and then call your .ToList or anything... You can use select anyway but I don't suggest this way.
Hope helpfull.

Comment: Any way if you want your app be fast, using select. but if you want coding fast mapster is the best library I know.